# BaseCamp export whole project

Tags: download, export, basecamp

I need to export project from BaseCamp. There used to be utility for XML export, but now it's missing. Is there any tool or way how to export/download it?

I've tried app HTTrack, but it can't go throught the log in page.

I am using "old" version of BaseCamp.

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can export basacamp classic projects with token key which is given in My info page.